# How get output like this using talend

Tags: data-warehouse, talend, business-intelligence, tmap

I have the dataset like this [image: dataset]

and want out put like this how can I do that[image: output][image]
Here is sample dataset

```
ID  COMP_ID CAR_ID  ENGINE  COLOR   CC
1   c1  car3    xyz blue    2500
2   c2  car4    xyz white   1000
3   c1  car6    xyz green   3500
4   c2  car1    xyz black   4500
5   c3  car5    xyz green   4000
6   c1  car2    xyz red 3000
7   c2  car3    xyz gray    1500
8   c3  car4    xyz silver  2000
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? One possible way would be using tAggreateRow and/ or tDenormalize.

Comment: I did nothing just thinking how can i did this

Comment: Stack Overflow is no code production service. This question is very broad and involves many steps. It would be a good start to see at least a job layout you thought about. The community is happy to help for specific questions.

Comment: sir actually i am using talend and try tmap, taggregate and like these components. after getting below answer i used tjavarow and tdenormlized but not successful yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a tJavaRow something like :

```
output_row.foo=input_row.row1+"\n"+input_row.row2;
```

foo must exist in your Output Schema 
and row1 and row2 in your Input Schema

Else, you can concatenate them in a TMap in the same way.

Comment: thanks sir using tmap and tdenormlized i got the desired output